# Two models into one paginated query with eager loaded relations using Laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have two  Models that I would like to merge into one timeline. I have been able to do this by creating a View in mysql that normalizes and unions the tables. I created a Model for this view, `NewsFeed`. This works well if I do not want related `Comment` model. I have gotten close to this by overriding the [`getMorphClass`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Relations/MorphOneOrMany.php) method on the model. This allows me to get the related comments for the pictures, but not the posts, because when `getMorphClass` is called the model doesn't have any data.

I am open to any approach on how to solve this, not just the way I am proposing, but I don't want to pull more data than I have to from the database.

**NewsFeed**

```
    <?php

    namespace App\Users;

    use App\Pictures\Picture;
    use App\Social\Comments\CommentableTrait;
    use App\Posts\Post;
    use App\Users\User;
    use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

    class UserFeed extends Model
    {
        use CommentableTrait;

        public function user()
        {
            return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
        }

        public function getMorphClass(){
            if ($this->type == 'post'){
                return Post::class;
            }
            return Picture::class;
        }
    }
```

**MySQL View**

```
CREATE VIEW 
   `user_feeds`
AS SELECT
   `posts`.`id` AS `id`,
   `posts`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,
   'post' AS `type`,
   NULL AS `name`,
   NULL AS `thumbnail`,
   `posts`.`body` AS `body`,
   `posts`.`updated_at` AS `updated_at`,
   `posts`.`created_at` AS `created_at`
FROM 
    `posts` 
UNION SELECT
    `pictures`.`id` AS `id`,
    `pictures`.`user_id` AS `user_id`,
    'picture' AS `type`,
    `pictures`.`name` AS `name`,
    `pictures`.`thumbnail` AS `thumbnail`,
    `pictures`.`description` AS `body`,
    `pictures`.`updated_at` AS `updated_at`,
    `pictures`.`created_at` AS `created_at` 
FROM
    `pictures`;
```

**pictures table**

```
    id
    user_id
    title
    img
    img_width
    img_height
    img_other
    description
    created_at
    updated_at
```

**posts**

```
    id
    user_id
    title
    body
    created_at
    updated_at
```

Comment: can't you just use eager loading? $var = Picture::with('posts','comments')...

Comment: The closest would be to get User::with(['posts','pictures'])->get(); which doesn't get you paginated content. I thought of doing something like `$user->posts()->paginate(15);` and `$user->pictures()->paginate(15);` then merging the collections, but it gets problematic once you want additional record sets.

Comment: why not paginate `User::with(['posts','pictures'])->paginate(15);` or even `User::with(['posts','posts.comments','pictures'])->paginate(15);` and pull a comments method on the posts model too?

Comment: because that gets you 15 users, not one user with with a mixed set of 15 pictures and posts based on created_at date.

Comment: You could `collect` all the results and paginate from there.  `collect([$user->posts, $user->pictures])->sortBy('created_date')->forPage($page, 15);`

Comment: so you just need to get one user and paginate pictures and posts ? `$user = User::where('whatever', '=',$userVariable')->first();   $post_pics = Posts::where('posts.user_id','=',$user->id)->where('posts.created_at', '=', 'timestamp')->join('pictures','posts.user_id','=','pictures.user_id')->oderBy('posts.whatever')->orderBy('pictures.whatever')->paginate(15);`  or order by Raw Rand(something); to get a mix of posts / pics within your date frame

Comment: @user3158900 does that pull all post and picture records and then get the last 15 or only pull 15 records from the database?

Comment: Probably not the answer you were looking for, but maybe it's time to just write a SQL native query instead of fighting with AR.

Comment: @Bogdan Unfortunately, I need to access the related models and use a lot of built-in methods on them.

Comment: Have you tried something like this? `$user = User::first(); $user->setRelation('posts', $user->posts()->paginate(15)); $user->setRelation('photos', $user->pictures()->paginate(15));`

Comment: @ThomasKim I need to paginate a feed of both models sorted by created_at date. This get problematic after the first query.

Comment: could you add your models of comment and newsfeed?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are really close with your idea to build a view. In fact, if you create an actual table instead of a view, the solution becomes quite simple.

With a 'FeedItem' polymorph object that points to your Post class or Picture class, you can attach the comments directly to the FeedItem with a hasMany relationship.

```
class FeedItem extends Model {
    use CommentableTrait;
    public function feedable()
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }
}

class Post extends Model {
    public function feeditem()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('FeedItem', 'feedable');
    }
}

class Picture extends Model {
    public function feeditem()
    {
        return $this->morphOne('FeedItem', 'feedable');
    }
}
```

This solution may require some refactoring on your forms since you will need to create a FeedItem entry for each Post entry and Picture entry. Event listeners for Picture::created and Post::created should do the trick (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events).

Once it's set up, you can use:

```
FeedItem::with('comments')->orderBy('created_at','desc')->paginate(15);
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I am not familiar with Laravel nor Eloquent for that matter, Here's my input on this.

Assuming you're getting the output from that SQL view into `$Entries`

As I understand Eloquent allows you to set the values for yourself, therefore something like this might work for you (I am not sure about the syntax or usage for that matter).

```
$Collection = [];
foreach( $Entries as $Entry ) {
    if( $Entry->type === 'post' ) {
        $Collection[] = new Post($Entry->toArray())->with('comments');
    }else{
        $Collection[] = new Picture($Entry->toArray())->with('comments');
    }
}
return $Collection;
```